# JavaFX : Clean up a TableView instance from Memory

Tags: java, memory, javafx

How should i clean up a `TableView` instance from memory,

From what i learnt,

1. Remove all `listeners` attached to the table. (is it applicable even to the respective table's columns and rows?)
2. Clear all columns.
   and
3. No strong reference to the table instance.

From an external reference i did the following,

1. set focus model to null.
2. set mouse,key listeners to null.
3. `setSelectionModel` to null.
4. `setItems` to an empty `ObservableArraylist`.

Finally, My code looks something like below.

```
 //I gave a try for, RowFactory and ColumnFactory to null.    
            tableView.setRowFactory(null);
            for (TableColumn column : this.tableView.getColumns()) {
                column.setCellFactory(null);
                column.setCellValueFactory(null);
            }
            tableView.getFocusModel().focus(null);
            tableView.setOnMouseClicked(null);
            tableView.setSelectionModel(null);
            tableView.getColumns().clear();
            tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
            tableView = null;
```

**My problem is:**

I have multiple table views opened and when i close, (`HashMapNode`(got from profiler) related to `TableView` is still on memory and not released)
So whenever i close a tableView i call the above code.

Also, I use inner classes to `setCellFactory` like below,

```
column.setCellFactory((TableColumn<?, ?> param) -> new EditingTableCell());

private class EditingTableCell extends TableCell<?, ?> {
//.....
}
```

So, How should i properly clean up a `TableView` instance so that it will be garbage collected.

> **Java Version**  : 1.8.0_45
>
> **JavFX Version** : 8.0.45-b11

Comment: It is not clear from your question, but - do you actually remove it from the scene graph?  
Also - is this actually a problem? Even when an object is no longer referenced, there is no guarantee if and when the GC will decide to collect it, as long as there is enough free space, so it may be possible the GC simply doesn't bother collecting it.

Comment: @sillyfly To be precise, question is what are the steps to be done on TableView instance so that it will be GC'ed(at some point). like remove it from scene graph as you said.    Yeah i do remove it from scene graph. and i understand its up to GC when to collect it, but it isn't collected even when no enough free space is available am pretty sure it resides in memory.

Comment: removing listners attached to the table is true. But setting `setonmouseclicked` to null isn't the right way to remove listner. verify that you really remove listners added with addListner or bind

Answer (score 0):

**3** (*No strong reference to the table instance*) should be enough.

Listeners are weak references that do not prevent the GC from cleaning up the object, if there are no more strong references to it.

However, if the TableView is contained within a Tab, it might not be GC'd upon tab closing, because JavaFX in its internals keeps a strong reference to the last closed tab (a gotcha it took me a while to find out - I consider it an undesired bug-like behaviour).